# Getting not found page after uploading my laravel project on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

When I uploaded my laravel project to Heroku host and go to the home page I found the laravel homepage (welcome.blade.php) that is fine but when a try one of my routes I get a page that  says NOT FOUND
now i have edited my Procfile to redirect me to routes folder then when I try one of my api routes a get this message The requested URL was not found on this server.

I tried this route on local server and it works

my Procfile :

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 routes/
```

my api file :

```
Route::post('/users/register' , 'App\Http\Controllers\AuthController@register') ;
```

my .env file

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:PecXeFHeAtspGD2s79k4F5HNh2mwgJEC7B1j7/a5cPU=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=storeappdb  
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

my database.php file

```
$DATABASE_URL=parse_url("uaodyzzuglhswm:f3e63e876b4eb6ffde66a69e7cc2942d639d0a98ad8107e5ab262c7219efc92d@ec2-54-164-241-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5jmfh2osra85q");

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),

  'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => $DATABASE_URL['host'] , 
            'port' =>  $DATABASE_URL['port'] ,
            'database' => ltrim($DATABASE_URL['path'] , "/"),
            'username' => $DATABASE_URL['user'],
            'password' => $DATABASE_URL['pass'],
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'schema' => 'public',
            'sslmode' => 'prefer',
        ],
```

Comment: you get a webserver 404 page or a Laravel 404 page?

Comment: i get a laravel 404 page

Comment: what URL are you trying to access?

Comment: https://darklord963.herokuapp.com/api/users/register

Comment: that is a webserver 404 page, not a Laravel 404 page .... your webserver isn't configured to use pretty urls / url rewriting

Comment: yes I have edited the procfile to redirect me to routes folder for that the error have changed
this url should return a json file but it gives me this page

Comment: your webserver is not configured properly and you don't redirect to routes folder

Comment: my Procfile have this : 

web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 routes/

Comment: what is with the `routes` part? ... the document/web root of your site should be the `public` folder

Comment: then how can I access my api routes ?
can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your document root is supposed to be the `public` folder of your application. So your "Procfile" needs to reflect that:

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

The document root is set to the `public` folder because the only accessible part of your application is what is in `public` (hence the name 'public'). The `index.php` file in `public` is the entry point to your application (Front Loader or Front Controller). The webserver will internally rewrite the URLs to pass off to this script (which is what the `.htaccess` file in `public` is setting up).

Comment: thx bro u are the best